# Unable to use XMLReader for an xml file on a remote machine

Tags: c#, remote-access, xmlreader

I have an xml file located on a remote machine that I'm having trouble accessing with `XMLReader`. Locally, it works fast and great, but for the life of me, cannot figure out how to get access on a remote machine.
I've tried using `XMLSecureResolver` with:

```
XmlSecureResolver resolver = new XmlSecureResolver(new XmlUrlResolver(), uriPath);
resolver.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, password, domain);

XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.XmlResolver = resolver;
```

but I get the error `Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.`

I've tried:

```
XmlUrlResolver resolver = new XmlUrlResolver();
resolver.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, password, domain);

XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.XmlResolver = resolver;
```

but I get `The user name or password is incorrect.`

And the credentials used are definitely correct since they come from the same runsettings file to log on to that remote pc.

As for `using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(uri, settings))` I was thinking maybe the uri isn't formatted right. What I'm using is `\\FullQualifiedDomainName\C$\SpecifiedDir\TheFile.xml` which works for me on my local machine (to the remote - manually).

As far as file and folder permissions goes, it's "full control"

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried just using default credentials (which will be yours)?

Comment: Just checked
`resolver.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;` Gives me the same `The user name or password is incorrect.` error

Comment: Hm. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlurlresolver?view=netcore-3.1 says : `XmlUrlResolver is the default resolver for all classes in the System.Xml namespace. It supports the file:// and http:// protocols and requests from the WebRequest class.` So I don't think it supports UNC paths. I imagine you can just use a standard approach for that using XmlReader.Create() and passing in the file path

Comment: Wait you mean I can just do a normal directory path as if it's local but pass in default credentials? I feel like I'm over thinking this.

Comment: No that doesn't work, that means I can ONLY connect via a mapped drive? There's gotta be workaround. Maybe managementscope? That's silly it can't support UNC.

Comment: Maybe I can use Powershell script to accomplish this

Comment: You should just be able to read directly from the fileshare, same as if it was a local path. I just tried it myself on a file on one of my network fileshares. Super-simple test like this, without any messing about with resolvers: `XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("\\\\server\\folder\\test.xml"); var x = reader.Read(); Console.WriteLine(x); reader.Close();` . It worked fine, no errors, and writes True to the console as you'd expect. (Note the escaped backslashes for including in a string literal). When I tried it on a fileshare I don't have permission to, I got an Access Denied error.

Comment: So I'd suggest that, most likely, you have a permissions problem (and therefore switching to powershell wouldn't solve anything).

Comment: well hmm, now I'm stumped. Also sidenote: Thank you for checking back with me so often. 
If the file is on the remote machine, how are you logging on to that machine?  By Fileshare do you mean allowing a share folder? Unfortunately, I'll need to authenticate as if I'm RDP.

Comment: "how are you logging on to that machine"...I'm not, because it's a shared folder. I'm running the C# code on my local machine, and accessing the shared folder from the local machine. So the C# opens the shared folder automatically using my windows network credentials, just as it would if I'd navigated to the folder manually using windows explorer. I don't need to do anything explicit to make that happen,  Windows just checks the permissions the same as it would for a path on my local C drive.

Comment: Why do you think you need to authenticate like you would for RDP? Your sample file path (`\\FullQualifiedDomainName\C$\SpecifiedDir\TheFile.xml`) looks like a normal shared folder (UNC) path to me. All you need to do is make sure your account (or the account under which the C# code will run, if different) has permission to read from it - this can be done from the security settings for the folder or file. Have you tried to do this using the code sample I gave (but using your path instead, obviously!)? What exactly was the result?

Comment: For clarity, you should try to execute `XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("\\\\FullQualifiedDomainName\\C$\\SpecifiedDir\\TheFile.xml"); var x = reader.Read(); Console.WriteLine(x); reader.Close();` in a console app running on your local machine. (Obviously I assume that's not actually the real path, but you know how to swap out the names)

Comment: So, I'm realizing now that I left out a detail. The remote machine is not on the same domain. 
To answer your question on the test.xml - same issue with the error: `The user name or password is incorrect.` I thought the resolver would solve this issue since it holds a user, pass, and domain and authenticate, but it... clearly doesn't. And that's why I was stumped on how you got it to work. Seemed like a security issue to me. 
Powershell is definitely not one of my strengths, but I know I can authenticate successfully that way - but I really don't want to, heh.

Comment: I see. That is a significant detail, yes! How would you authenticate across domains to that fileshare in powershell then, out of interest? Maybe we can work out the .NET equivalent. ( I suspect your attempt didn't work maybe because it tries to authenticate to your local Active Directory, not the remote domain's. Unless there's a specific trust relationship set up between the two directories, then it would not normally have the ability to check with the remote domain's directory).

Comment: Unfortunately I wasn't the one that built our method to get our powershell scripts to work remotely but it appears to use System.Management.Autionation.PSCredential to pass in a username and password 

`$"$password = ConvertTo-SecureString '{password}' -AsPlainText -Force; " +`
`$"$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential('{username}', $password); " +`
`$"Invoke-Command -ComputerName '{hostname}' -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock ";`
And then you append whatever PS commands after that and it runs on that remote machine.

Comment: And yeah, good point about it trying to authenticate on the local AD. It begs the question what is the point of the resolvers then? But in any case, it looks like I might have to go the PS way. I just know even less about that than I do about XMLReader :)

Comment: Ah. The powershell Invoke-Command command will (when you specify a computer name), actually run the command on the remote computer directly, as if it was executing there to begin with. So, quite different to trying to read a fileshare from one computer to another. That's why it works. I don't know of a way to do that in .NET tbh. But a) .NET code be run from Powershell, and b) Powershell code can be executed from .NET. So whichever way round you approach it, I'm confident you could build a hybrid solution for this task.

Comment: Thank you for the help @ADyson. I think what I'll do is, I'll translate what I have into a powershell script, update this question, and post the solution. I looked more into the resolver and looks like it's only for accessing external DTDs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it comes down to using powershell Invoke-Command which works great. Let me START with what I WANTED to do. The following takes a very large XML file that's responsible for holding various tables and definitions that can be imported into a database. The process of importing can take quite a lengthy time, especially if you need to test against an export. This is what was meant to be a solution:

```
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.Async = true;
string table = string.Empty;
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(sourcePath, settings))
{
    while(await reader.ReadAsync())
    {
        switch (reader.NodeType)
        {
            case XmlNodeType.Element:
                if (reader.Name.Equals({theElementToCheckAgainst}))
                {
                    if (reader.GetAttribute("Name").Equals(tableOfInterest))
                    {
                        table = reader.ReadInnerXml();
                        break;
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return table;
}
```

The above really didn't need to be async, so if you wanted to, you could use reader.Read() instead of reader.ReadAsync(). Anyway, this was not working when I needed to test for exports happening on remote machines that were on a different domain.

We have a method that uses Powershell Invoke-Command to access our remote machines and it looks something like this:

```
string script =
$"$password = ConvertTo-SecureString '{password}' -AsPlainText -Force; " +
$"$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential('{username}', $password); " +
$"Invoke-Command -ComputerName '{hostname}' -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock ";
```

hostname is the FQDN without slashes.

We then append the script with

```
script += $"{{ {scriptBlock} }};";
```

In my case, scriptBlock =

```
$@"$xmlfile = ""{sourcePath}""
$reader = [System.Xml.XmlReader]::Create($xmlfile)

while ($reader.read())
{{
    switch ($reader.NodeType)
    {{
        ([System.Xml.XmlNodeType]::Element)
        {{
            if ($reader.Name -eq ""{theElementToCheckAgainst}"")
            {{
                if ($reader.GetAttribute(""Name"") -eq ""{tableOfInterest}"")
                    {{
                        $null = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load(""System.Xml.Linq, Version = 4.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = b77a5c561934e089"") #This was added because I kept getting an error with System.Xml.Linq without it. You may not need it.
                        $result = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::ReadFrom($reader)
                        return $result.ToString()
                    }}
                    break
                }}
                break
            }}
        }}
    }}";
```

Finally, we use the Invoke-Command to execute it all:

```
PowerShell powerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create();
powerShellInstance.AddScript(script);
return powerShellInstance.Invoke();
```

Now, our method has a few company-specific things in there that I can't show but I hope this helps anyone who needs this.

And thank you to @ADyson for helping me realize my issue.